# How is Spring actually bootstrap?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

1. Does anybody know how Spring is actually bootstraps?
2. Which instances created and by whom?
3. I really want to know who creates instances of WebApplicationContext and ContextLoader. Is it work of Tomcat?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## Servlet context listener (web.xml) approach

1. A web application WAR is being deployed by **user**.
2. **Servlet container** (Tomcat) reads `web.xml`.
3. Servlet context listener [`ContextLoaderListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html) is being instantiated (if defined as `<listener>` inside the `web.xml`) **by servlet container**.

   1. **`ContextLoaderListener`** creates new [`WebApplicationContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) with application context XML configuration.
   2. Your ROOT context beans are registered and instantiated by **`BeanFactory`** inside the application context.
4. [`DispatcherServlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) is being instantiated **by servlet container**.

   1. **`DispatcherServlet`** creates its own `WebApplicationContext` (`WEB-INF/{servletName}-servlet.xml` by default) with the ROOT context as its parent.
   2. Your servlet beans are registered and instantiated by [**`BeanFactory`**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html?is-external=true) inside the application context.
   3. **`DispatcherServlet`** registers some default beans in case you did not provide them yourself.

## Servlet container initializer (non web.xml) approach

This one is possible with Servlet 3 features.

1. A web application WAR is being deployed by **user**.
2. **Servlet container** searches for classes implementing [`ServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) via Java's [`ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).
3. Spring's [`SpringServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html) is found and instantiated **by servlet container**.
4. **Spring's initializer reads** web application's class-path and searches for [`WebApplicationInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) implementations.
5. Your `WebApplicationInitializer` is found (btw. **check its JavaDoc!!!**) and instantiated **by `SpringServletContainerInitializer`**.

   1. **Your `WebApplicationInitializer`** creates new ROOT [`WebApplicationContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) with XML or `@Configuration` based configuration.
   2. **Your `WebApplicationInitializer`** creates new servlet [`WebApplicationContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) with XML or `@Configuration` based configuration.
   3. **Your `WebApplicationInitializer`** creates and registers new `DispatcherServlet` with the context from previous step.
6. **Servlet container** finishes the web application initialization and instantiates components which were registered by their class in previous steps (*none* in my example).

Java based approach is much more flexible. You can leave the context creation to `DispatcherServlet` or even the whole instantiation of `DispatcherServlet` itself to servlet container (just register servlet `DispatcherServlet.class` instead of its instance).

Comment: And how is Tomcat find ContextLoaderListener if I not specify listener in my web.xml?

Comment: `ContextLoaderListener` (from the first scenario) must be declared as `<listener>` inside your `web.xml`. Structure and placement of `web.xml` is well defined by Servlet specification. Tomcat knows where to find that file and what to do with its contents.

Comment: <web-app version="2.4"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <servlet>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Comment: It's my web.xml. And Spring with Tomcat someway do they job without listener.

Comment: I mean that in my default example I didn't add some listener and all works.

Comment: Listener is not mandatory. Without it you just won't have any *ROOT* application context. Having a root context with application components (DAO, Service, data sources, transaction infrastructure, security) and leave servlet context to UI components (handler mapping, handlers/controllers, view mapping) is somewhat a good practice.

Comment: Is Tomcat check classpathes for all listeners to initialize them?

Comment: Nope... Tomcat is not locating any *listener* implementations. If you don't define it, Tomcat won't instantiate it.

Comment: But you wrote "Servlet context listener ContextLoaderListener is being instantiated by servlet container". It is true, but my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml is not contains any listeners.

Comment: Then this step and its substeps are skipped. Updated answer with a condition.

Comment: FYI Some versions of Tomcat 7 work with the second "non web.xml" approach, some don't. I found 7.0.27 does not work, and 7.0.69 does work. HTH someone

Answer (score 3):

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-create.

The principle is to declare a ServletContextListener in the standard webapp descriptor (web.xml). Such a listener is indeed instantiated by the container and is called when the application is initialized and when it's destroyed.

Spring provides such a ServletContextListener: [ContextLoaderListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html) which, as its name indicates, loads a Spring context when the webapp is initialized.

Comment: Is a `ServletContextListener` actually the best place to e.g. execute SQL migration scripts? At the moment I am not sure how and when my production server is going to apply such scripts and currently I am thinking about doing this in `ServletContextListener#contextInitialized`.