# spring webapp without web.xml and without any spring xml config file

Tags: spring-mvc, servlet-3.0, spring-java-config

below is a piece of code taken from

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-webflow-samples/blob/master/booking-mvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/webflow/samples/booking/config/DispatcherServletInitializer.java

```
public class DispatcherServletInitializer  extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {
        SecurityConfig.class,
        DataAccessConfig.class,
        WebMvcConfig.class,
        WebFlowConfig.class
    };
}
....
}
```

There is no web.xml in this project. There are no spring xml config files, so also no context:component-scan xml tag.

**How does spring know, that it should execute getRootConfigClasses from DispatcherServletInitializer ?** Does spring scan for classes implementing WebApplicationInitializer ? If so, where is it configured to scan for such classes ? 
Is there some default web-fragment.xml in META-INF in some spring jar ? If so in which jar is it ? In spring-web-4.0.5.release.jar there is only < name > spring_web < name > < distributable/> in spring-webmvc.jar there is no web-fragment.xml.

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714290/how-is-spring-actually-bootstrap/21714524#21714524

Comment: Thx Bohuslaw, Your link answers my question.

Comment: You can find configuration details at WebMvcConfig.java and WebFlowConfig.java files from the project in the same package.