# newest way of using launching spring in a web app

Tags: java, spring

I've recently seen some a use of the newest Spring in a Web Application. I was interested in how that spring application was launched with Tomcat because I haven't seen anything inside web.xml or another dispatcher servlet. Probably the dispatcher servlet is created using a class but... How?

Comment: Take a loot at this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21714524/1291150. It describes the non-web.xml approach of bootstrapping Spring app

Comment: I think you are looking for Spring 4 example,have a look,https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/spring-mvc-full-java-based-config/

Comment: You may want to see http://www.javamexico.org/blogs/jpaul/ejemplo_basico_con_spring_mvc_xmlless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that when you say *use of the newest Spring in a Web Application* you are talking about Spring 4 and in particular [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

Spring describes Spring Boot like this:

> Spring Boot makes it easy to create stand-alone, production-grade Spring based Applications that can you can "just run".

So, how does it work to get a stand-alone web application up and running? The answer is simply that you declare some dependencies in your `pom.xml`, add an application launcher (a classic old `main`-method) that invokes a method from Spring Boot which starts *the whole thing*. The *whole thing* in this case scans the codebase for your components and then starts the embedded container (Tomcat) that was declared in your `pom.xml` - after that you are all set!

The application launcher typically invokes the `SpringApplication.run`-method that starts the embedded web container. You can also apply a set of annotations that e.g. defines which packages that should be scanned or what type of components that can be used. Examples include: `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`. The various annotations typically can be used to either replace some older XML-tags or to set some nice defaults [convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration).

From the [spring.io blog](http://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications):

> When you run your application, Spring Boot will detect that you have a Spring MVC controller and start up an embedded Apache Tomcat 7 instance, by default.

So, this basically means that Spring Boot will fire up a Tomcat but you can use other containers as well (such as Jetty).

To get the whole thing started, simply add the following dependency to your `pom.xml` and the project is Spring Boot enabled:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then create the application launcher:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String index() {
        return “I am alive”;
    }

    // The application launcher, starts a simple controller running in the Tomcat container
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        // Start an application with your IndexController
        SpringApplication.run(IndexController.class, args);
    }
}
```

I really recommend the [Spring Boot documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/). Some other useful resources on the matter are:

- [how-is-spring-actually-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714290/how-is-spring-actually-bootstrap/21714524#21714524)
- [Spring Web](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-web)