# Why there is no Application Context in spring mvc application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, ioc-container, applicationcontext

I was looking at spring mvc source example (pet clinic) and was a bit confused. How I'm suppose to instantiate beans (getBean method) without having an application context. How spring does autowiring without it.

Comment: Which example are you referring to?

Comment: There *is* a context, and you should almost never use `getBean` directly.

Comment: @minion I use this example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/

Comment: Application context is created automatically during application bootstrap phase. Take a look at this post for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21714524/1291150

Comment: classpath:spring/mvc-core-config.xml contains your webapp context configuration and classpath:spring/business-config.xml, classpath:spring/tools-config.xml contains your business layer configuration. What are you looking for exactly?