# How is Spring Boot actually bootstrapped?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I went through this question on Stack Overflow - [How is Spring actually bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714290/how-is-spring-actually-bootstrap)

It talks about the Spring, and I want to know the exact process in the case of Spring Boot.

In case of web.xml

1. How the execution starts when the Spring Boot WAR is deployed on Tomcat
2. Does the class containing the `main()` get executed first or the class extending the `SpringBootServletInitializer`? What is the flow?

In case of web.xml, in the official doc here [Create a deployable war file for older servlet containers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file-for-older-containers), it says we need to add a web.xml to our application and configure it to load an ApplicationContext via a DispatcherServlet. How do we do that?

Looks like I have configure like this, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```xml
<servlet>
    <!-- Provide a Servlet Name -->
    <servlet-name>frontcontroller-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <!-- Provide a fully qualified path to the DispatcherServlet class -->
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <!-- Provide a Servlet Name that you want to map -->
        <servlet-name>frontcontroller-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <!-- Provide a url pattern -->
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: `1.5.22` ??? Spring boot 1.5 OSS support (06 Aug 2019), Commercial Support (06 Nov 2020) (https://endoflife.date/spring-boot) , why play old version ? and end of support ?

Comment: Hello, I couldn't find the docs for servlet containers in the latest version. Official docs only explains about cloud deployment.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#web, search in web page ` war `

Comment: Thanks and the process for web.xml application remains the same. how do we load the application in case of web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

The `main()` method in the WAR package does not run in the Tomcat container.

For example, the following part of the code

```java
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
@Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(UserApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this get called by servlet container?

Comment: Yes, it will load at startup.

Comment: How do we call it using web.xml?

Comment: SpringBootServletInitializer implements the WebApplicationInitializer interface.   WebApplicationInitializer is provided by the spring web and invoked initially by the tomcat container(Code principle: SpringServletContainerInitializer implements ServletContainerInitializer,  javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer.onStartup )

Comment: If your version is not very old, you don't need web.xml.

Comment: I have older version :(

Comment: Just find a reference site, whether as matching with your version, https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-09/springboot-tomcat/